# generate insert script from model in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

is there any option how to generate data insert script in EF from model? For example: I have a tables(objects) structure like: People->Customers->Orders...

I want to load one instance of the People recursively....People people = peopleRepository.GetByKey(1)
and from this people instance I want to generate insert script for all child objects like:

```
insert into people(id, name, ...) values (1, john...)
insert into customers(id, peopleid) values(1, 1)
insert into orders(id, customerid) values (1, 1)
insert into orders(id, customerid) values (1, 2)...
```

is this possible in EF?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not any such tool. You must write it yourselves. Simply call

```
var person = context.People.Include("Customers.Orders").Where(p => p.Id == 1);
```

and use data to create insert scripts.